# i have a question about python dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble with dictionaries in Python. I'm a new learner. I have a homework problem that I'm working on and I'm struggling to finish the homework problem. Can someone give me some thoughts about ways to code this problem?

# I want to know some thoughts about how to begin this homework problem that I have.I have tried a lot of things already and I'm still having trouble.

```py
trans = {'0':'ling', '1':'yi', '2':'er','3':'san', '4':'si','5':'wu', '6':'liu' ,'7':'qi', '8':'ba', '9':'jiu', '10':'shi'}

def convert_to_mandarin(us_num):
    ## us_num , a string representing a US number 0 to 99
```

`convert_to_mandarin('26')` will return `er shi liu`; `'30'`, `san shi`.

can someone help me how to approach this problem?

I'm having trouble with getting numbers to print above 10. I am supposed to write a piece of code that will return the Chinese "number" for the English number (for example "36" should be returned "san shi liu".) And if it's 14, then it should return "shi si".

````
trans = { '0':'ling', '1':'yi', '2':'er', '3':'san', '4':'si', '5':'wu', '6':'liu', '7':'qi', '8':'ba', '9':'jiu', '10':'shi'}

def convert_to_mandarian(us_num):
    ten = 'shi'
    chinese_trans = ''
    for n in str(us_num):
        if n in trans.keys():
            chinese_trans += trans[n]
        else:
            if n > 10:
                chinese_trans +=str(ten) + trans[str(us_num[-1:])]
            chinese_trans += trans[str(us_num[:1])] + str(ten) + trans[str(us_num[-1:])]

        if n == 10 or n == 20 or n == 30 or n == 40...........90:
            chinese_trans += trans[str(us_num[:1])] + str(ten)

    return chinese_trans


print(convert_to_mandarian('14'))will return shi si
--------------------------('36')will return san shi liu
--------------------------('20')will return er shi```


When I run my code, I only get less than 10. So, for example, for 36 I get "san-liu" instead of "san shi liu". What am I doing wrong? I'm a new learner of Python, so I'm sorry if this question isn't very specific.
````

Comment: This is a trivial problem. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What are you having difficulty with? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
trans = { '0':'ling', '1':'yi', '2':'er', '3':'san', '4':'si', '5':'wu', '6':'liu', '7':'qi', '8':'ba', '9':'jiu'}
def conv(number): #function which should accepts numbers
    try:
        num_str = str(number) #Converts to string
        if len(num_str) == 1:
            num_str = '0' + num_str #Adds e10 numeral position
        else:
            num_str = num_str[-2:] #Keeps last two digits
        if num_str[0] == '0':
            e10 = ''
            e01 = trans[num_str[1]] # Grabs the corresponding dictionary element for e01 position                   
        elif num_str[1] == '0':
            e10 = trans[num_str[0]] + '-shi' # Grabs the corresponding dictionary element for e10 position
            e01 = ''
        else:
            e10 = trans[num_str[0]] + '-shi' 
            e01 = ' ' + trans[num_str[1]] 
        return e10 + e01
    except Exception as e:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Edit: Added the some exceptions

Comment: THANK U VERY MUCH  for your HELP:)

Comment: @NaingNaing, if the answer helped you, you should consider marking it as the [Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one

Comment: yes, Thanks u for your help .It is very helpful, and i learn it from you some. i really appreciate it ,Thanks a lot.Angle Santiago Jaime Zavala.